# Scroll Fixed Div Upon Collision

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a page with two fixed divs (div1 and div2) at the top and one div (div3) with the page content that flows naturally below. When the user scrolls and div3 reaches the bottom of div1, I want the two divs to fuse together and scroll normally. This [website](http://shun.kaiusaltd.com/) has the exact behavior I'm trying to replicate.

I am using different z-indexes to keep the div1 and div3 above div2, and detected when div1 and div3 touch:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var calc = $("#div3").offset().top - $("#div1").height();
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= calc) 
    {
        //fuse
    }
    else
    {
        //unfuse
    }
});
```

But I can't figure out how to fuse div3 and div1 together.

Thanks :)

Comment: The elements are most likely not “fused together” – but the fixed positioning is just changed to absolute so that the formerly fixed elements scroll with the rest of the content …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. It relies on `.header` and `.content-inner` within `.content`. `.header` is displayed as `position:fixed` until the scrolling threshold is reached at which time a class is added to `.content` and `.header` switches back to `position:static` so it's back in the regular flow of the page.

`.content-inner` was necessary because we need to reduce the `margin-top` to make room when `.header` goes back to static positioning.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/GkwEc/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content-inner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,
html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.banner {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:100px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#F00;
}

.content {
    margin-top:400px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    position:relative;
}
.content.fuse {
    margin-top:300px;
}

.content-inner {
    background-color:#FFF;    
}

.header {
    position:fixed;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00F;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

.content.fuse .header {
    position:static;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300)
        $('.content').removeClass('fuse');
    else
        $('.content').addClass('fuse');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tyriar. I understand your solution but was unable to retrofit it into my existing code and ended up redesigning the page in the manner you suggested. So, it works! But I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around the concept. For example, this [page] (http://www.npr.org/blogs/health/2013/03/20/174872904/how-a-sleep-disorder-might-point-to-a-future-youll-forget?utm_source=NPR&utm_medium=facebook&utm_campaign=20130322) is pretty interesting but I can't figure it out. Do you know of any good resources I can read to catch up? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: @bre that page is likely using something very similar, just handling `$(window).scroll()` and changing styles on the elements when they reach a certain threshold.